# Auto deploy on kubernetes

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, github, kubernetes, github-actions

I have a branch on Github that I do pull request from it and add some feature and create a new feature branch .So I have master branch ,feature 1 Branch ,feature 2 branch..etc .
what I want is to auto build docker image of each image of each feature branch of them then deploy them on kubernetes and expose a service of them with url(kubernetes is on AWS).After that if I approve the feature branch after pull request to the master,delete its deployment on k8s.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This can possibly be done by using githooks on the server-side, and/or triggering your CI to accomplish what you are looking to do.

Comment: can i contact you to explain more ?

Comment: Sure - please do send me a 1x1 message - I will try to help

Comment: how can i send you ? .. if you can send me a message on my linkedin acc. : https://www.linkedin.com/in/ahmed-nageh-0921b9128/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GitHub you can achieve this using **GitHub action** and if you are on GitLab you can also do it using the **GitLab CI pipeline**.

here is whole example with configuration : https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2017/09/21/how-to-create-ci-cd-pipeline-with-autodeploy-to-kubernetes-using-gitlab-and-helm/

```
For feature branch you can keep different config name, service name, deployment name. 

in CI add the logic if branch name if staging 
apply the feature Yaml with command 

kubectl delete -f .....if branch name is feature apply the yaml with command

kubectl apply -f
```

it's simple thing however you might have to update question with more details.

Comment: i'm using github but i don't know how to do that using github actions & exposing a service from it using ingress or something

Comment: yes you have to expose the service using the ingress, what you can do is create on special repo for yaml files and each time apply those yaml files to kubernetes cluster when PR get merged. You can add logic into the CI for same

Comment: can i contact you for more info ?

Comment: sure you can contact on my linked n in bio.

Comment: yu have a locked messages if you can send me on : https://www.linkedin.com/in/ahmed-nageh-0921b9128/